# Access data files from within a python package

Tags: python, audio, package

I am trying to play a wav file based on the character the user inputs.
My project structure looks like:

```
mypkg/
 |
 | mypkg/
    | 
    | __init__.py
    | code.py
    | sound/
        |
        | A.wav
        | B.wav
        | ...
 |
 | setup.py
```

I have added the following in `setup.py`:

```
package_dir={'mypkg': 'mypkg'},
package_data={'mypkg': ['sound/*.wav']}
```

My `code.py` looks like:

```
files = {
        'A': 'sound/A.wav',
        'B': 'sound/B.wav',
         ...
}
c = raw_input()
f = files.get(c, '?')
...playing the wave file code...
```

I know `'A': 'sound/A.wav',` is wrong. The problem is everything runs fine if I use the code as a script, but I get an IO error if I run `setup.py` and then import this as a module in the console. Specifically:
`IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'sound/S.wav'`

I know I have to use `pkgutil.get_data()` but then how can I add the correct path to the files in my `files` dictionary. What should my `code.py` look like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that, when you run a script, the current location of that script is where you run it from, assume you run the script from a totally different location using `absolute path` , then the current location inside that script is the location you were in when you ran the script, not the location of the script.

For your example, in your `code.py` , you need to get the location of that python file and then append the data file to that location, before using it.

To get the location of the python file being run, you can use `__file__` , or the better - `os.path.realpath(__file__)` , you need to understand that `__file__` would give the complete path of the file, to extract the directory you have to use - `os.path.dirname()` .

Then your code would look like -

```
pt = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
files = {
        'A': os.path.join(pt, 'sound/A.wav'),
        'B': os.path.join(pt, 'sound/B.wav'),
         ...
}
```

Comment: Getting an error:
`IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\
\morse_talk-0.1.1-py2.7.egg\\morse_talk\\enunciate.pyc\\sound\\A.wav'`

How to eliminate enunciate.pyc?

Comment: Fixed, please check now.

Answer (score 2):

There is another way but working with `data_fles` from `setup.py`:

**setup.py**

```
setup(name='dcspy',
  version=__version__,
  ...
  data_files=[('dcspy_data', ['images/dcspy.ico'])],
  ...
```

When you `pip install` will put `data_files` here:

```
$ pip uninstall dcspy
Found existing installation: dcspy 1.1.2
Uninstalling dcspy-1.1.2:
 Would remove:
  d:\python38\dcspy_data\dcspy.ico
  d:\python38\lib\site-packages\dcspy-1.1.2.dist-info\*
  d:\python38\lib\site-packages\dcspy\*
  d:\python38\scripts\dcspy.exe
Proceed (y/n)? y
```

you can access them in your package like:

```
root = tk.Tk()
root.iconbitmap(f'{sys.prefix}/dcspy_data/dcspy.ico')
```

Information: [2.7. Installing Additional Files](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/setupscript.html#installing-additional-files)